# Set focus to child element inside control template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a control template for a control derived from `CheckComboBox` control of Extended WPF Toolkit (almost the same as standart `ComboBox`). I'm trying to track when key is pressed on this control while its dropdown part is open to modify some of its properties. But when I open dropdown and press any key nothing happens (breakpoint is hit neither inside `OnKeyDown` nor inside `OnPreviewKeyDown` overriden methods). They start to being hit only if I previously clicked on a control inside dropdown part. So how could I make them work even if child control doesn't have focus or how can I set focus to child control when drop down is open. For the latter I tried to use trigger in ControlTemplate.Triggers collection but it can't find child element neither with `{x:Reference ChildControl}` nor with `{Binding ElementName=ChildControl}`.

Here is a XAML snippet for template

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type wpfApplication2:DropDownMultiSelector}">
        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            <!--This one doesn't work-->
            <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_Popup}" />
            </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <Grid x:Name="MainGrid" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
            <Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" AllowsTransparency="True" IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" Margin="1" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" Placement="Bottom" StaysOpen="False">
                <Grid MinWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=MainGrid}">
                    <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowFrameBrushKey}}" BorderThickness="1" Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}" MaxHeight="{Binding MaxDropDownHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <ScrollViewer x:Name="DropDownScrollViewer">
                            <Grid RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Enabled">
                                <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="0">
                                    <Rectangle x:Name="OpaqueRect" Fill="{Binding Background, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=DropDownBorder}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=DropDownBorder}"/>
                                </Canvas>
                                <ContentControl x:Name="ChildControl" Content="{TemplateBinding ChildItemsControl}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Popup>
            ...
```

Comment: Have you tried calling Focus() in code behind?

Comment: @Bizz no, I didn't. I wonder is it possible to get reference to ChildControl from code? I mean is it a part of logical/visual tree?

Comment: I guess not since it's inside a Popup

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but try deriving from ContentControl and add a dependencyproperty (IsFocused) to it and bind it to IsDropDownOpen. Then add a callback for IsFocused in which Focus() is called

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What helped me is setting focus to control itself, not to its subcontrol.

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsDropDownOpen" Value="True">
        <Setter Property="FocusManager.FocusedElement" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" />
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Answer (score 1):

Liste to Loaded event and set focus.

Here is an example how to handler events in XAML :)

```
<Grid>
    <!–Define the button content –>
    <Button Width="133" Height="24" Name="btnExitApp" Click="btnExitApp_Clicked" Content="Exit Application"/>
    <!–The C# implementation of the button's Click event handler. –>
    <x:Code>
        <![CDATA[            
            private void btnExitApp_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
            {
                // Get a handle to the current app and shut it down.
                Application.Current.Shutdown();
            }
        ]]>
    </x:Code>
</Grid>
```

Yes you can write code in XAML! :)

Comment: Isn't it a bit dirty approach?

Comment: think like this.. if it was dirty, microsoft wouldnt allow it :)

Comment: Interesting approach) but sorry, I'll try to avoid it

Comment: do what you have to do